# django to use settings.py at a different location

Tags: django

I having issues getting Django to work with settings.py at different location

I have a folder setting with test.py as copy of settings.py

Folder laid out as

```
   models.py
   settings.py
   setting/
       test.py
```

this one works with default location

```
SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE myproject.settings

python manage.py syncdb  --settings="myproject.settings"
```

this does not work when tring to use file in a subdirectory

```
SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE myproject.setting.test

python manage.py syncdb  --settings="myproject.setting.test"
```

Error

```
Error: Could not import settings 'myproject.setting.test' (Is it on sys.path? 
Does it have syntax errors?): No module named setting.test
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your `setting` directory needs an `__init__.py` file so it is a valid Python [package](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Answer (score 1):

The more elegant way to split the settings for various kind of purpose is to replace the settings.py to settings as module and the original settings.py will be moved under settings, and rename to **init**.py like this,

```
   models.py
   settings/
           __init__.py
           test.py
```